# Before & After pseudo-elements not working on Safari

Tags: css, safari, pseudo-element

I'm working on a website where a section of the homepage is appearing differently in Safari to Chrome.

On Chrome I can see that the code is using before & after pseudo-elements for styling, using the following code:

```
.home-about:before {
    content: "";
    background: #efebe8;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    top: 0;
}

.home-about:after {
    content: "";
    background: rgb(255 255 255 / 70%);
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 50%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

This works fine on Chrome, but not on Safari. Unfortunately, I'm on a Windows and can't seem to find any option to download Safari to work it out myself. Does anyone know what might be causing the code not to run in Safari?

Answer (score 0):

I have the current version of Safari (16.3) on a Mac, and can confirm that the snippet below works just fine. So I don’t think there’s anything wrong with your code. Contact whoever reported that it didn’t work, and check which version of Safari they’re using, and which operating system and version.

Going forward, you should be using `::before` instead of the deprecated `:before`, and `::after` instead of the deprecated `:after`, but the deprecated syntax still works at the current time.

```css
.home-about {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

.home-about:before {
    content: "";
    background: #efebe8;
    height: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    top: 0;
}

.home-about:after {
    content: "";
    background: rgb(255 255 255 / 70%);
    height: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 50%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-about"></div>
```